# Google Analytics Tag is firing, but does not show up in GA dashboard anywhere

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set up Google Analytics Tag Manager to track PDF clicks on my site. When I use preview mode on the site, it says the correct tag fires on the page. It looks like it's doing what it is supposed to, but in Google Analytics no event shows up anywhere. I also checked Events (Last 30 Min) but nothing showed there either.

I do not have an internal traffic filter for this. Google Tag Assistant Chrome Extension's tag analysis only showed that the Google Analytics UA has a non-standard implementation. I have verified that the code is installed on the website and has the correct GTM-XXXXXXX number.

Code that was added to the head:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5377XP7');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Code that was added to the body:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5377XP7"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Tag Manger settings:
Track Type : Event
Category: News
Action: Select
Label: PDF
Google Analytics Settings : {{Google Analytics Settings}}

Trigger Configuration:
Trigger Type: Click - Just Links
Wait for Tags
Page Url: contains/
Cluck URL: contains .pdf
References to this trigger: UA - Event - PDF Click (name of the above event)

Debugger gave one error that said:
Tracking ID not set. Aborting hit.

Comment: The details in the post are relevant for the GTM implementation, but contain no information on the tag and trigger setting. Can you verify in the developer console network tab, or with Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, that the hit is actually sent to Google Analytics? Can you share your event tag settings?

Comment: I wrote out the settings, because I don't have enough points to post pictures yet

Comment: "Tracking ID not set" seems like a pretty clear indicator of what the problem is, and "aborting hit" means the event was never sent to GA due to this error... It sounds like in your {{Google Analytics Settings}} GTM variable, the field for "Tracking ID" is either empty, or set to a non-valid tracking ID value (perhaps ID is set as the value of another GTM variable?).

Comment: @JoshuaT that really helped and I fixed the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same message when trying to set up Google Tag Manager with a [lookup table](https://www.napkyn.com/2017/07/12/ga-gtm-environments/).

I have a simple setup, and I just wanted to vary the Analytics ID by hostname.

Somewhere along the line nothing was getting passed, despite having a default value configured.

A fun debugging trick is to add a `Custom HTML` tag and then you can put all your variables in a `console.log` statement. It even autocompletes for you!

[image]

```
 <script>
   console.log('GTM Debug - {{Page URL}} - {{Hostname_TO_Analytics_ID}}'); 
   console.log('GTM Debug Analytics', {{Google Analytics}});
 </script>
```

Note that you can put `{{ VariableName }}` without quotes when it is an object (like `{{Google Analytics}}` is - and you'll get a nice expandable item in the console.

[image]

It turned out for me I think to just be a caching issue - and I actually did have things correct.

So...

**Important: Sometimes your old tag gets cached**

- Enable Network > Disable Cache in Chrome to prevent this (remember to turn off later)
- I'm not 100% sure the Google policy on tags propagating - but be aware you may need to refersh

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure enter GA tracking Id correctly (google analytics traking id).
[image]
2.Save and click on refresh
[image]
3. Refresh your site and test again